# 2006 Hyundai Santa Fe stalls in the rain

Tags: hyundai, santa-fe

I just bought a used Hyundai Santa Fe 2.6 engine.  This car stalls out every time it rains. You go through a puddle and the battery and brake warning lights come on and it loses power steering and brakes.

I was told the belt could be getting wet and slipping. I'm now afraid to drive this car. I live in Florida and it rains a lot here. It's scary when you don't know if you are gonna stall out when you make a turn, but it seem to do it when the weather is damp.

Any ideas about what could be causing this problem?

Comment: I have a 2008 Hyundai Tucson and it does the exact same thing. I have had this in the shop so many times I have lost count. They have changed belts, checked the spark plugs and electrical. They look at me like I'm crazy. So I can't wait until January when this POS gets traded in! And I'm done with Hyundai! This is very scary when you're driving on a wet road and you lose control of the car when the battery light / power steering stalls.

Comment: Yes it is Carol, I just had my belt and tensioner replaced hoping to fix it. It will rain here today so I am going to see if it does it again. Only in the rain for me too.

Comment: If the car is stalling when driving in the rain I'd suspect the crank position sensor is getting wet. Have you had it checked for stored codes? Also If the belt were slipping you'd hear it.

Answer (score 3):

The number 1 reason for stalling problems when the weather is damp is tune up issues. Generally worn spark plug wires being the main cause. Get a spray bottle and fill it with tap water and just a little bit of salt. Use the spray bottle to lightly wet down the spark plug wires while the cars is running. If the engine stalls then you need a tune up. if there is a central coil be sure to wet that down as well.

Comment: I disagree. What about the battery and brake warning lights? Looks more like an electrical issue. Short circuit due to water getting in somewhere it is not supposed to.

Comment: Generally when water shorts something out, it kills it permanently or at least causes long term issues. Spark plug wires just tend to come and go with dampness. The warning lights are just what happens when the engine stalls and not a symptom. Also there is no mention that the car does not restart for a long time.

Comment: Doesn't need restart, when the warning lights go out everything returns to normal.  Only seem to happen when I hit standing water. Lights come on, power steering and brake not working but car still moving. Engine runs smooth and quiet even when warning lights come on.

Comment: @Deborah "Stalls out" means that the engine SHUTS OFF. If the engine keeps running and only the lights come on, those are completely different symptoms. With the updated symptoms i would then say it's a belt issue.